# Ruby on Rails & Calling methods with Symbols Basic Question

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, symbols

For some reason I haven't quite gotten the hang of how Rails interacts with Ruby / figured out Ruby itself.

I'll get to the point.  For example in a Ruby on Rails project you might have something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
default_scope :order => 'title'
end
```

This confuses the crap out of me.  I assume we are calling the method default_scope which Product inherits from the base ActiveRecord class... so that we can set some options.  We pass it the symbol :order => 'title'.  is :order just a hash value within the default_scope function and it is setting that hash value as 'title' ?  Am I getting that correctly.

Also for example, when you start to throw basic validation in you get something like this

```
validates :price, :numericalcity => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01 }
```

I know what this does but its syntax blows my mind.  First it looks like symbols are used for static reused string values, but here we are sending in a dynamic symbol in... where is that going?  And then are we a symbol within a symbol?  Is that basically a hash within a hash or what exactly is it doing?  I'm just trying to trace it out within my brain to actually understand what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in assuming `default_scope` being a method, which is inherited from ActiveRecord::Base. Go [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope) to view the source code of `default_scope`.

**It is a method which takes an optional Hash as it's only parameter**.

This,

```
default_scope :order => 'title'
```

is the same as writing it as,

```
default_scope( { :order => 'title' } )
```

In ruby if a method is defined like,

```
def foobar(options = {})
  p options
end
```

But **beware** of a subtle difference in syntax. Above, if you leave out the `()` keeping the `{}` ruby understands it as something entirely different. Ruby sees a method `default_scope` which accepts a `code block` as it's argument.

```
default_scope { # code block }
```

This method definition will look like,

```
def foobar(&block)
  yield
end
```

To understand how ruby blocks work [read this](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/009-beautiful-blocks.html).

You can call it like,

```
foobar :key_1 => 'value_1', "key_2" => 'value_2'
```

And Ruby understands it to be,

```
foobar( { :key_1 => 'value_1', "key_2" => 'value_2' } )
```

The keys of the Hash may or may not be symbols.

As for the validation helper method for the column attribute `price`,

```
validates :price, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01 }
```

Is the same as,

```
validates( :price, { :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01 } } )
```

This is similar to a method definition like,

```
def validates(column_attr, options = {})
  # perform validation of column_attr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
default_scope :order => 'title'
```

Is a method call

```
default_scope( {:order => 'title'} )
```

Ruby allows you to omit parentheses and braces in this case.

```
validates :price, :numericalcity => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01 }
```

means

```
validates( :price, {:numericalcity => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01 } } )
```

Comment: your example is wrong: `default_scope {:order => 'title'}` is considered a block and not a hash parameter. You should write `default_scope ({:order => 'title'})`